# How do I rename the file in file_put_contents?

Tags: php

I have this code snippet that grabs a SWF file and saves it locally. Works like a charm! However, I need to rename the file and have no idea how to do so. All help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
$filename = "filename"; //Without extension
$urls = array($swf_url);
foreach($urls as $url) {
   $data = file_get_contents($url);
   file_put_contents('/home/public/'.basename($url), $data);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rename+file+php

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+rename+file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... Just give it a different name in the first place...

```
file_put_contents('/home/public/' . $someothername, $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply save it with the name you want:

```
file_put_contents('/home/public/whatever/you/want.swf', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not simply change where you're writing it in the first place?

If you read the [documentation of file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), you'll know that the first parameter `$filename` is the filename. All you need to do to write it to a different place is change that first parameter.

Namely, modify `'/home/public/'.basename($url)` to be whatever you want.

If you really want to rename a file, you can use the [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) method of PHP like so:

```
rename('/home/public/' . basename($url), '/home/public/newname.swf');
```

.. but that makes little sense.

Answer (score -1):

```
rename('oldname.swf', 'newname.swf');
```

You can read more [in the documentation](http://php.net/rename).